# Child element appearing behind img

Tags: html, css

I've only just managed to wrap my head around parent / child hover actions (mostly), but I'm having trouble with this one.

I have an arrow in a child element (h3.test) that I want to appear on hover of the parent (category-links).  The problem is that the arrow appears **behind** the (img.art-icons) element.  I know I'm probably doing something retarded here, but can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/plaedien/mN7mZ/

CSS

```
.button {
    width: 225px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a.category-links{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #F0F5F5;
}

h3.test{
    padding-top: 11px;
    padding-bottom: 11px;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a.category-links:hover h3.test{
    background: url(http://kmmedia.com.au/~~test/images/yellow-arrow.png) #b61f25 center 45px no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}   

.art-icons {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.category-text {
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="button">
    <a class="category-links">
        <h3 class="test">Hapkido</h3>
        <img class="art-icons" src="http://kmmedia.com.au/~~test/images/hapkido-icon.png" alt="pic">    
        <div class="category-text">Do you want to learn practical<br>self-defence skills?  Then Hapkido is the martial art for you!</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your arrow isn't behind - it's because you have set it as a background and moved it down 45px so your h3 isn't tall enough to show it, which is why it is cut off at the bottom of the h3

If you want a work around, you can try change your h3 to:

```
<h3 class="test"><span class="arrow"></span>Hapkido</h3>
```

and then use the following styles:

```
a.category-links:hover h3 {
    background:#b61f25;
}
a.category-links:hover .arrow {
    background: url(http://kmmedia.com.au/~~test/images/yellow-arrow.png) center top no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    display@:block;
    width:23px;
    height:12px;
    top:45px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-12px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/mN7mZ/15/)

[Or to show the arrow underneath the h3](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/mN7mZ/17/)

Comment: After reading all of the answers I realised I wasn't clear enough about what i was trying to do.  You are correct, I was trying to get the arrow to show UNDER the h3.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: no problems, glad I could help, just noticed a typo in my answer - there shouldn't be an @ in the `display:block` line

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the image is set relatively as a background and it will only show based on the height of the actual h3 div, which is 23px, and hence the cutoff. Add the following to h3:hover.

```
h3:hover {
  height: 40px;
}
```

This fiddle will show you what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/mN7mZ/5/

Answer (score 0):

I would just increase the `padding-bottom` on `h3.test` to provide enough space for your arrow to show, I've also increased the `padding-top` so that the ratios look ok:

```
h3.test{
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vM7S/).

Answer (score 0):

Reduce value of center to 38px in:

```
 a.category-links:hover h3.test{
background: url(http://kmmedia.com.au/~~test/images/yellow-arrow.png) #b61f25 center 45px no-repeat;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Increase the padding top and bottom value to 15px... it will work fine

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mN7mZ/11/)

**CSS:**

```
h3.test {
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    background-color: #cbcbcb;
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    h3.test{
padding-top: 11px;
padding-bottom: 18px;
background-color: #cbcbcb;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
color: white;
font-size: 23px;
font-weight: 600;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
}

a.category-links:hover h3.test{
background: url(http://kmmedia.com.au/~~test/images/yellow-arrow.png) #b61f25 no-repeat;
position: relative;
color: #fff;
z-index: 9999;
background-position:50% 43px;
padding-top: 11px;
padding-bottom: 18px;
}
```